2-homogenous actions
Let us define a half $2$-transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ as an action with the two following properties :
1° the operation is transitive;
2° for every distinct elements $x, y$ in $X$, for every distinct elements $z, t$ in $X$, there is an element $g$ in $G$ such that {gx, gy} = {z, t}. (Sorry, but I have a problem with brackets in LaTex.)
(This has something to do with $2$-homogenous actions, but I don't know exactly what conditions are required for an action to be called $2$-homogenous.)
We can note that if $X$ has at least $3$ elements, 2° implies 1°.
Clearly, a $2$-transitive action is a half $2$-transitive action.
If $G$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group, the reciprocal is true, in other words :
Let $G$ be an elementary abelian $2$-group, with a half $2$-transitive action on a set $X$; this action is $2$-transitive.
Here is a proof.
Assume that the action is not $2$-transitive. Then, there exists an element $x$ of $X$ such that the action of $G_{x}$ (stabilizer of $x$) on $X \setminus {x}$ is not transitive. In other words,
there exists an element $x$ of $X$ and two distinct elements $y_{x}$ and $z_{x}$ such that
there is no $g$ in $G$ such that $g\ x = x$ and $g \ y_{x} = z_{x}$.
Since the action of $G$ on $X$ is assumed to be half 2-transitive, this implies that
there is an element $h$ of $G$ such that
(1) $hx = z_{x}$
(2) and $h y_{x} =x$.
From (2) results $h^{2} y_{x} = hx$, where, in view of (1), $hx$ can be replaced by $z_{x}$, thus
(3) $h^{2} y_{x} = z_{x}$.
Since we assume that $G$ is an elementary abelian $2$-goup, we have $h^{2} = 1$, so (3) gives $y_{x} = z_{x}$, contradiction.
My question is : do you know other types of groups such that a half $2$-transitive action of such a group is necessarily $2$-transitive ? Thanks in advance.
